# Get error in Nusoap: XML error parsing SOAP payload

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm new on Soap\NuSoap 
I can connect to server site but from server send data back to client i can not get data in array to show client site. I have to test to get data and send data back to other database. I have to get in array.

it's show error

```
XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end
```

I can't fix it by myself. please help.

This is my client.php

```
include("lib/nusoap.php");
$client = new nusoap_client("http://192.168.20.3/soap_server/webservice.php?wsdl");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
$client->encode_utf8 = false;
$client->decode_utf8 = false;
$params = array(
        'strName' => $_POST["strName"],
);
$result = $client->call("resultCustomer",$params);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    exit();
}

print_r($result);
```

And this is server.php

```
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");     

    //Define our namespace
    $namespace = "http://localhost/soap_server/webservice.php";
    //Create a new soap server
    $server = new soap_server();
    //Configure our WSDL
    $server->configureWSDL("getCustomer");
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
    $server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
    $server->encode_utf8 = false;
    $server->decode_utf8 = false;

    //Register our method and argument parameters
    $varname = array(
               'strName' => "xsd:string"
    );

    //Add ComplexType
    $server->wsdl->addComplexType( 
        'ArrayOfString', 
        'complexType', 
        'array', 
        '', 
        '', 
           array( 
                'id_user' => array('name' => 'id_user', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
                'firstname'  => array('name' => 'firstname', 'type'  => 'xsd:string'),
                'username'  => array('name' => 'username', 'type'  => 'xsd:string'),
                'lastname'  => array('name' => 'lastname', 'type'  => 'xsd:string')
       ) 
    ); 
    //Add ComplexType
    $server->wsdl->addComplexType( 
        'ArrayOfString', 
        'complexType', 
        'array', 
        '', 
        'SOAP-ENC:Array', 
        array(), 
        array( 
            array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:DataList[]') 
        ), 
        'tns:DataList' 
    ); 

    // Register service and method
    $server->register('resultCustomer',$varname, array('return' => 'tns:ArrayOfString'));

    function resultCustomer($strName)
    {               
            $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
            $objDB = mysql_select_db("qpt-test");
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qpt_user where firstname like '%".$strName."%'";
            $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
            $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
            $resultArray = array();
            while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
            {
                $arrCol = array();
                for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
                {
                    $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
                }
                array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
            }
            return $resultArray;            
    }
    $POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';

    // pass our posted data (or nothing) to the soap service
    $server->service($POST_DATA);
    exit();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `nusoap` works, but it looks a lot more complicated than using the built-in PHP `SoapClient` and `SoapServer`.

Comment: If you're defining WSDL, I would do it as an XML file, rather than in PHP. It will be much easier to understand.